# jQuery Tabs with listed content

Tags: jquery, list, tabs

So, I'm not sure if it's something I've done wrong or an issue with jQuery. But when having listed content within a tab the list formatting is removed.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        <ul>
            <li>A list which isn't a tab</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

$("#tabs").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

When I use jQuery to initialise the tabs upon document ready, the list format from the second list get removed. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: it could be that the jqueryui stylesheet doing that. try to add the styles under the jqueryui stylesheet or inline incase other styles are conflicting

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835127/jquery-tabs-unformatted-list-flashing-up-after-an-jquery-html-reload-in-firefox ?